# Is there a way to merge two users?

Tags: users

I have two users and I would like to merge then into one.

All the answers I could find online to this question focus on transferring ownership of posts, but this is a network site and I need to transfer permissions and roles as well.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Just delete one of them - WordPress will ask if you want to attribute their posts and links to another user.

Comment: That doesn't transfer permissions or roles.

Comment: Which roles/capabilities does each user currently have?

Comment: Write permissions on different sites in the network. User defined roles on various sites.

Comment: Sounds like you'd need some (possibly complex) logic to parse permissions. WordPress won't do this for you, so id say that no there isn't an easy way.

Comment: Maybe it's prime time for a plugin to do a merge...?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking I agree with most of the other answers but, if for some reason you really had to *merge* two accounts here is how that could work.

Merging User-B into User-A

1. Reassign all of User-B's content to User-A
2. Determine the highest privilege of User-B
3. If higher than the privileges of User-A elevate User-A's privileges else do nothing.
4. If you have extended the WordPress's native users account you'll want to add that logic here too.
5. Delete User-B and do some clean up.

Comment: Sounds good to me :-) Thank you so much for the step-by-step approach...

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot merge two users. What you can actually do is add the new user then transfer all the posts to him.

When you add the new user you can define his rule. In your case the new user should be an 'Admin'. Thus he will have access to all the contents as well as rights for everything. Moreover this simple process is also very easy to perform

Answer (score 0):

What's easy to do is transferring posts of a user to another user. I think you can just simply delete it and transfer everything to an existing user. But user roles… I'm not sure why you'll have to transfer that to another user. Can't you just simple create another user with the same permiossions and merge the posts of both?

Answer (score 0):

Check this plugin, will be beneficial for you https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-merger/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).